# Accessing mutlidimensional array of custom class not returning element

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to create a multidimensional array of a custom class (PeopleInfo).

```
public class PeopleInfo {

    public String name;
    public String address;
    public Integer houseNumber;
    public String job;
    public String title;

    public PeopleInfo(String name, String address, Integer houseNumber, String job, String title) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
        this.job = job;
        this.title = title;
    }
```

In the java file creating the array, this is a fragment within a tabbed application:

```
public class Employees extends Fragment {
    PeopleInfo[] testArray = new PeopleInfo[] { new 
    PeopleInfo("Joe","Bloggs",4,"cleaner","Mr"), new 
    PeopleInfo("Kim","Lim",34,"CEO","Mrs.")};

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.employees, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        Log.d("TEST", testArray[0].name);
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return testArray.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout,null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textView_title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
            TextView textView_info = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView_info);
            Button button_one = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_go);
            Button button_two = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_info);

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

When printing elements of the array in onViewCreated using the following statement it returns 0.

```
Log.d("TEST", testArray[0].name);
```

printing the length of the array returns 2.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: more code, please. `onViewCreated` , etc.

Comment: Can't find an error in your code. Works fine. The bug must be somewhere else.

Comment: share your fragment code!!!

Comment: added the full code! Question is why is the print statement returning 0 instead of the element information